# How do I teleport an armor stand to an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am designing a redstone mini-game, and I need the game host to be able to  set spawnpoints.

I was thinking that the host would drop an item (say red wool) and an invisible armor stand named "Red" will be spawned there. Same with green wool.

The player (based on team) would then be teleported to the proper armor stand. I just can't figure out how to place the armor stand via a dropped item. Any ideas?

Comment: Downvote? Please do explain.

Comment: Hint: Try fiddling around with `/execute` command.

Comment: Downvote? Of course. Arqade is a Q&A site, while your question, although also meets Q&A requirement, is more like a "I-want-to-do-this-now-help-me" post, which we discourage and give down votes. You may want to edit your question and post what problems you have during the design of the game, rather than just asking people "how to do this", while without any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To teleport an armorstand to an item, as you say in your title:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Red] @e[type=Item,...]
```

Where `...` is whatever you're using to identify the item (name? scoreboard value? location?).

To spawn an armorstand at an item, as you say in your question:

```
/execute @e[type=Item,...] ~ ~ ~ /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Red"}
```

Again, where `...` is however you're identifying the item. I'd recommend using a scoreboard value based on their item ID, like this:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isRedWool 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:14s}}
```

Where isRedWool is a dummy objective.

Comment: Thanks! I came across this myself and was going to post it. But, they work. Take +15 rep.